# Is it possible to prevent windows in Mac OS from opening below the bottom edge of the screen?

Tags: macos, display, osx-leopard, window

When opening a new window in finder, the new window will go below the screen.  This is not a big deal, but when using macvim or terminal it can be annoying since your command prompt is now hidden.  Firefox seems to be smarter, it never overlaps below the screen.

Same deal for the right hand side of the screen, windows often open with their right edge cut off.  Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: I assume you're using Snow Leopard. I never had that issue, tho. In fact, if I keep pressing Command + N on finder, I'll have a cascade effect and then loop to the top - new windows will never go off the screen.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned leopard

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to fix the issue specifically, but I can say that [SizeUp](http://irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) has been a huge help to me.

The whole floaty-windowed, laid-back attitude of OS X to window positioning still bugs me after 4 years of mac use. SizeUp lets you assign keyboard shortcuts for maximising windows, and positioning them in fixed locations with fixed sizes, like the top-left quarter of the screen.

Worth every penny.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.  I'm not as irritated by the Mac OS X window handling, but I'm very impressed with SizeUp's screen cast on their site.  Thanks!